# Use the property of a navigation property as its own property

Tags: entity-framework

So I am using the entity framework code first, and I have a `Place` class containing a bunch of `Road` object:

```
public class Place : EntityData
{
    ...
    public List<Road> Roads {get; set;}
}
```

And the class `Road` contains a bunch of `Segment` objects:

```
public class Road : EntityData
{
    ...
    public List<Segment> Segments {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to add a `List<Segment>` in the `Place` class, which is the total of all the children `Segment` that belong to the `Place`'s `Road`s. So the new `Place` should look like this:

```
public class Place : EntityData
{
    ...
    public List<Segment> Segments {get; set;}
    public List<Road> Roads {get; set;}
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Segment> Segments { get {
    List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

    ... go through all Roads and add all their segments to segments variable ...

    return segments;
}}
```

Comment: Navigation property defines relationship between two entities. If there is no direct relation between Place and Segment, then Segments is not a navigation property for Place entity.